# Find all records until this time - MySQL

Tags: mysql

All,

I have a column with values ranging in time i.e.

```
Sun, 22 May 2011 20:15:00   
Fri, 20 May 2011 10:15:00   
Thurs, 19 May 2011 09:15:00   
Fri, 20 May 2011 13:15:00
```

and suppose the date/time now is `Fri, 20 May 2011 15:00:00`.

I want to only retrieve those records created today until this point i.e. until `Fri, 20 May 2011 15:00:00`.

How can I do that?

I know `CURTIME()` gives the time at this point, but how do I vary the difference from midnight 12am to current time?

Comment: Is that the format the date/times are stored in? You may want to use the DATETIME format instead, or store the dates as INTs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE datetimecolumn BETWEEN date(now()) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this

> Retrieve those records created today until this point i.e. until Fri, 20 May 2011 15:00:00

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE datetimecolumn >= date(now())  -- current date without the time
AND datetimecolumn <= '2011-05-20 15:00:00'
```